# How to bring WiFi back up if woken from deepSleep(WAKE_RF_DISABLED)

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to build a sensor that should update an MQTT broker only if something changes. So every few seconds it's supposed to wake up just enough to check a few inputs, compare them with the last time it woke up, and only if there has been a change should it connect to the broker and write the updates. I don't expect many updates per day, but if I sleep more than 10 seconds, I might miss them.

I'm using `WiFi.forceSleepBegin()` and `WiFi.forceSleepWake()`, mainly based on [these articles](https://www.bakke.online/index.php/2017/05/21/reducing-wifi-power-consumption-on-esp8266-part-1/). But there is this tempting option of `ESP.deepSleep(n, WAKE_RF_DISABLED)`

The [API](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#esp-specific-apis) that I found only mentions this:

> If you implement deep sleep with WAKE_RF_DISABLED and require WiFi functionality on wake up, you will need to implement an additional WAKE_RF_DEFAULT before WiFi functionality is available.

Do I read this correct if I understand that I would need to make another `deepSleep` just to wake up again with WiFi back active? Or is there an easier way to boot up the WiFi after such a sleep?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
WiFi.forceSleepBegin();
delay(1);
WiFi.forceSleepWake();
delay(1);
```

Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/3072#issuecomment-741524721)

That also works, I tested it December 2020.  Thanks to Erik Bakke for finding it.  It's a bit more clean than another Deep Sleep boot with the modem enabled.  Igrr and I both struggled to find a way to wake the modem, and Erik mixed the magic sauce.  Hopefully it still works today with the changes to the core WiFi files.

Comment: This is not really an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you understood correctly; after using `ESP.deepSleep(n, WAKE_RF_DISABLED)` to disable WiFi, the most reliable method to re-enable it is to call `ESP.deepSleep(1, WAKE_RF_DEFAULT)`. Then connect to WiFi on the next wake (which should be in 1 second). [Apparently](https://hutscape.com/tutorials/wakeup-with-no-radio), `WAKE_RFCAL` and `WAKE_NO_RFCAL` also result in WiFi working.

A cheap way to approach this, is to normally sleep with `WAKE_RF_DISABLED` but when your WiFi connection fails, sleep with `WAKE_RF_DEFAULT` to make the next connection more likely to be successful.

If you want a more elegant, but slightly more complex solution, you can use the [RTC memory](https://hutscape.com/tutorials/rtc-memory) to store the known WiFi state when you sleep; so when you sleep with `WAKE_RF_DISABLED`, you'll know that you'll have to reset with `WAKE_RF_DEFAULT` before trying to connect. And, when you wake again, you'll know the WiFi has been enabled.

As mentioned in [another answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/85289/78174), after using `WAKE_RF_DISABLED`, you could call `WiFi.forceSleepBegin()` and then immediately call `WiFi.forceSleepWake()` to try to bring the WiFi back up without resetting. While I have actually found this to work, sadly it seems to be unreliable. Seems like it might work while on USB power, but when changing to another power source, it stops working. I'm not sure why. When using that approach, sometimes the MCU will consume only 40 mA when it's supposed to consume 70 mA with WiFi on, so this suggests to me that the WiFi doesn't properly initialize.

All that being said, I would suggest that using `WAKE_RF_DISABLED` is quite extreme. Like in your original solution, I have found that you can avoid using `WAKE_RF_DISABLED` altogether if you call `WiFi.forceSleepBegin()` immediately when the device starts (i.e. at the top of your `setup()` function), and then `WiFi.forceSleepWake()` when you want to use WiFi. When the device starts, there is only perhaps 50-100ms when the device is using 70mA before WiFi is turned off. This is probably acceptable for most low power designs.